# How to display the variables only once in Xquery?

Tags: xml, xquery, basex, xquery-3.0

I am trying to display three different variables at once. 
           Here is what i have tried.

```
         let $totalmovies := count(//Movies/Movie)
         let $averagevariton:=(count(//Movies/Movie/secondtitles/OtherTitleName) + count(//Movies/Movie/Title) ) div $totalmovies

         for $m in //Movies/Movie
         let $year := (max($m/secondtitles/Year) - min($m/secondtitles/Year))+1

         order by $year descending

         return ($totalmovies,$averagevariton,$year)
```

But at the moment, it keeps printing the values until for loop is done. How can I display those values only once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't clear what the correct output should be, maybe you want to use `for` loop only to populate the `$year` variable, something like this :

```
let $totalmovies := count(//Movies/Movie)
let $averagevariton:= (count(//Movies/Movie/secondtitles/OtherTitleName) + count(//Movies/Movie/Title) ) div $totalmovies
let $year := 
    for $m in //Movies/Movie
    let $diff := (max($m/secondtitles/Year) - min($m/secondtitles/Year))+1
    order by $diff descending
    return $diff
return ($totalmovies,$averagevariton,$year)
```

Comment: hi, there is no year in the output.

Comment: @user2775042 Please post simplified XML sample, and the ex pected output. This answer is the furthest I can (and willing to) guess. Thanks

Comment: sorry there was no year because of my fault.

Comment: @user2775042 please post the xml sample.